# How can I get the sub-navigation to show up in the sidebar on child pages

Tags: 7, blocks

Drupal newb here :) So I may not have the Drupal lingo correct in my explanation...

I have a menu block called "Sub Navigation".  Here are my configurations:

[image: configs1]
[image: configs2]

(I've inherited this site so I'm not sure if this is a default block or not etc)

So, the navigation shows up just fine in the sidebar of parent pages, but it does not on *any* child page. (The admissions parent page has a context configuration, is why it is omitted here).

Am I missing a configuration here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is the url of your child page  `/admissions`?

Comment: Some of them are, but it is also not showing up under any other child page...  for example, it shows on the About page -`/about`, but not on any About child page - `/about/presidents-office`, `/about/policies` etc

Comment: If the subpages use panels, blocks could be disabled. Just an idea before delving into the issue further.

Comment: I don't see the panels module installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help with this, and what it needed was for this checkbox to be selected:

[image]